# AVFoundation Recording Audio Feature, how to change language?

Tags: avfoundation, swift5

I want to implement the AVFoundation recording system (NOT SPEECH) but it seems to be set to detect only english. Is there any parameter to change?

Comment: can you please share some code that you have done so far?

Answer (score 1):

**Check language codes by:**

```
for voice in (AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()){
        print(voice.language)
    }
```

and the get it by below code:

```
let speakTalk   = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
let speakMessage    = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Hello, How are you?")

speakMessage.voice  = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
speakMessage.pitchMultiplier = 1.2
speakMessage.rate   = 0.5

speakTalk.speak(speakMsg)
```

It is what you need?

Comment: I record an audio through avfoundation, thanks to this i can recognize the spoken language?

Comment: This is a question!